# How can Mysql INSERT operations be optimized for possible duplicate entries?

Tags: mysql, node.js, multithreading, performance, query-optimization

In my NodeJs application, I am using a threads(defined by my self) to open ports in a computer. There is a restriction that only one thread should be bound to each port.

I am maintaining a table(PORTS) in Mysql which holds data about open ports and the bound thread. Currently I am using the following approach to avoid two threads being bind to the same port.

*=> Insert an entry to the PORTS table with port number as the PRIMARY KEY. This will throws the following error*

```
error inserting semaphore port:10014 error Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'port:10014' for key 'NAME'
```

*I capture this error and then try another port until an error is not thrown.*

Is this a good practice? Or should I first check if the value exists using a SELECT query and then INSERT entry if not? 
Note- AFAIK In the second approach, SELECT and INSERT can be run as an atomic operation by using an SQL Transaction.

Comment: The current method seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple 'clients' attempting to get 'ports' at the same time, your second approach is bad.  This is because a different client could sneak in between the `SELECT` and `INSERT` and grab the port.

Your first approach is better because it is 'atomic'.  And it is a single action, thereby being faster (not that speed is a big deal).

Comment: I forgot to mention. By the second approach, I am doing both operations in an atomic manner by using an SQL Transaction. I just care about performance in that case. Am I right?

Comment: True, it is about performance.  Since there are lots of possible ports, the error (and recovery from it) should be rare.